# How does antivirus know?

Tags: windows, anti-virus

I just tried to run one of my applications, it's a client that receives commands and enters them to the cmd. When I tried to run it, the Microsft defender removed it immediately and gave me this, Trojan:Script/Wacatac.B!ml.

The description also had this, This program is dangerous and executes commands from an attacker, how does it know what the application does without even running it? From what I've read already, I saw that `system()` could cause suspicion, but I haven't used it.

**P.S**

It's an assignment from school, technically it doesn't really matter whether it removes it or not, but I'm curious.

Comment: @Señor CMasMas The thing is that it took time for the antivirus to detect it. I kind of forgot about it, and then an hour later I had a warning from the antivirus. When I changed the name to "Driver.exe" it immediately quarantined it, so it's not that the antivirus is slow.

Comment: @Ramhound In this case I'm actually puzzled too. I see you voted it down for having too little information, but the question does state Microsoft Defender, the question is not edited, yet your first comment asks for what AV. Seems like you might not have read the question correctly and jumped the gun.

Comment: I have to wonder why my comment was deleted.  I didn't mean to offend anyone.. I just wanted to know why someone had voted him down.  My comments about how an antivirus works were also not wrong.  Sorry if I offended anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to antivirus software, they will not just halt a program the moment it does something bad. That makes it often too late. Instead, they will scan files based on key signatures.

When you make a program in a programming language, and you run it, it is compiled to an executable using an interpreter. This interpreter writes standardized instructions to create the executable. If certain code can be harmful to a system, it will contain a signature. This basically means, when you inspect your program instruction for instruction, a series of instructions in sequence will be identical and is known to be used for malicious code. This is called a signature.

In order for viruses to be stopped before the can do any damage, programs are scanned and halted for execution when launched. If such signature is found, then the program is removed if deemed serious enough.

In some cases, it is not a signature that is found but one of the first instructions being done, such as opening ports for listening that uses suspicious ports, often used in attacks, or attempts to write in certain locations or perform administrative tasks.

Comment: Does that mean I can mislead the AV by adding useless instruction between a suspicious sequence? For example, if `recv()` `system()` `send()` is counted as suspicious I can add `cout` or any other junk in between and it will be not suspected?

Comment: @LeoSegol no. It does not see a sequence of instructions as suspicious, if sees the opcode for just one instruction as suspicious. It counts that, and if that happens only once, then it may say: okay, might be false positive... but if it happens more than once, it may raise that as suspicious.

Comment: I understand, thanks a lot.